# Nodejs Background job strategy

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, kue

I have already implemented `kue` to handle background jobs, in my application, I have a huge amount of background processes that cause the server crash, Now I want to find a better solution or alter way for this.
One way I think is to have a separate process (application) for processing queue.
Any solution you guys suggest?

Comment: use try and catch method for better handling of errors. if some error occurred then it always caught in the catch, and the server will not crash anymore

Comment: Huge amount of background process? in NodeJS? Node is single process based that is the one of its biggest advantages. you might have alot of `kue` jobs to process, and I assume that the jobs functions you are running are flawed. 
Bear in mind that NodeJS is great in I/O bound applications, In case your app is doing alot of calculations and processing and its more CPU bound maybe you should think about other solutions then NodeJS.